# How to use “And” clause in Firebase Query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

We are developing hybrid mobile app using `Angular2` and `ionic2` and `Firebase`. We post data into firebase .We data like this

```
PinCode       blood group   Name           Age
--------      -----        ------         ------
534401         B+           Pavan          24
400084         A+           Alapati        35 
534333         B+           Sai            22
```

if user select  Pincode:534401 and blood group:B+. We need show particular  record data only.We tried like this

```
     this.showData = this.afd.list('/blooddetails/').$ref.orderByChild("pincode").equalTo(formData.pincode).ref.orderByChild("groupname").equalTo(formData.groupname);
        this.showData.on('child_added', function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));  
});
```

but we are getting OR case.We got two record form above table.first and last record.We need `AND` case.We tried Query also

```
this.showData = this.afd.list('/blooddetails/', {
  query: {
    pincode: formData.pincode,
    groupname: formData.groupname,
  }
});
```

But no lucky .Guide to us what we miss.